# I am having trouble adding data to my table on submit

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and trying to figure out how to enter information into a table onSubmit. i have tried to follow tutorials but when you are new, its difficult to know what your following. The output I hope to achieve is to enter a workout into the text box, choose a day for said work out and upon pressing the submission button, the work out populates the table matching the day chosen

I appreciate my code may not be great. However, any help here would be great.

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import WorkOutList from './components/WorkoutList';
//import WorkoutAdder from './components/WorkoutAdder';
import WeightAdder from './components/WeightAdder';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <WorkOutList />
      <WeightAdder />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

import React from 'react';

class WorkoutAdder extends React.Component {
  state = {
    workout: '',
    day: ''
  };

  handleInputChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Todays Workout is:{this.props.dayMatcher[0].exercise}</p>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
          <h4>Select a day to add workout </h4>
          <label htmlFor="day" id="day" />
          <select
            className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            type="text"
            name="day"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          >
            <option value="n/a">pick a day</option>
            <option value="Mon"> Mon</option>
            <option value="Tue"> Tue</option>
            <option value="Wed"> Wed</option>
            <option value="Thu"> Thu</option>
            <option value="Fri"> Fri</option>
            <option value="Sat"> Sat</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Workout Here"
            name="workout"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        <br />
        <p>
          <button
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}
            className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
          >
            {' '}
            Add Workout
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WorkoutAdder;

import React from 'react';
import WorkoutAdder from './WorkoutAdder';

class WorkOutList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    workout: [
      { exercise: '', day: 'Mon', weight: 0, dayNum: 1 },
      { exercise: '', day: 'Tue', weight: 0, dayNum: 2 },
      { exercise: '', day: 'Wed', weight: 0, dayNum: 3 },
      { exercise: '', day: 'Thu', weight: 0, dayNum: 4 },
      { exercise: 'Yoga', day: 'Fri', weight: 0, dayNum: 5 },
      { exercise: '', day: 'Sat', weight: 0, dayNum: 6 }
    ]
  };


  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(currentState => {
      let copyArr = [...currentState.workout];
      let newArr = copyArr.map(copy => {
        const copyWorkout = copy;
        copyWorkout.exercise = copyArr.push(this.props.handleInputChange);
        console.log(copyWorkout);
        return copyWorkout;
      });
      console.log(newArr);
      this.setState({ newArr });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const getToday = new Date().getDay();

    const dayMatcher = this.state.workout.filter(d => {
      if (d.dayNum === getToday) {
        return d.day;
      }
      return this.dayMatcher;
    });
    // console.log(new Date());
    // const theDate = new Date();
    // console.log(theDate.getDay());
    return (
      <>
        <WorkoutAdder
          dayMatcher={dayMatcher}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />

        <div className="grid-container">
          {this.state.workout.map(exercise => {
            return (
              <div className="grid-item" key={exercise.day}>
                {exercise.day}-{exercise.exercise}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default WorkOutList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since in the parent component `WorkOutList` you send the function `handleSubmit` to the child component `WorkoutAdder`. You can access it from the properties rather than from the component instance itself. so:

```
      <button
        onClick={this.handleSubmit}
        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
      >
        {' '}
        Add Workout
      </button>
```

should be

```
      <button
        onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}
        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
      >
        {' '}
        Add Workout
      </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First issue is you need to pass handleSubmit is not your class function in **WorkoutAdder** component i.e you need to fix like this :

```
<button
            onClick={this.props.handleSubmit} //need to add like this
            className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
          >
            {' '}
            Add Workout
          </button>
```

another issue is that you are not setting state properly in **handleSubmit function**. You do not need to do nestedSetState.

```
this.setState({ newArr });
```

What this does it it setting newArr state with newArr variable. In your case it should be workout.

The handleSubmitCode should be like this:

```
handleSubmit = (event,data) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Data",data);
    let copyArr = [...this.state.workout];
      let updateData = copyArr.map(stateData => { //check if it meets current one then update the excercise
        if(stateData.day===data.day){
          return {...stateData,exercise:data.workout,}
        }
        else{
          return stateData;
        }
      });
      this.setState({ workout:updateData }); //Update with new state
  };
```

Inside **WorkoutAdder** component

```
<button
            onClick={(e) => this.props.handleSubmit(e,this.state)}
            className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
          >
            {' '}
            Add Workout
          </button>
```

demo :

[image: Edit wizardly-hoover-u3lb6]

Comment: wow 'Shubham Verma' thats worked an absolute treat, thank you so much